# Rocket Propulsion Elements: Total Impulse Problem

Tags: propulsion, rockets, measurement, specific-impulse

I figured this is probably an okay place to post this question.

[image: From Rocket Propulsion Elements: Chapter 2, Problems]

I managed to get (a), (c) and (d) (quite simply), but I have absolutely no idea why I can't work out (b).

I used $$ I_{sp}=\frac{I_t}{g_0\dot{m}\Delta t} $$

I assumed thrust was constant (is this wrong?). I did also check my units.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You got caught by those silly English units.

Your expression, $I_t = I_{sp}g_0 \dot m \Delta t$, works just fine when you use metric units. The mass flow rate, in metric units, is 127 kg/s. The total impulse, in metric units, is
$$I_t = (217.5\,\text{s})(9.80665\,\text{m}/\text{s}^2)(127\, \text{kg}/\text{s})(65\,\text{s}) = 1.76\times 10^7\,\text{N}\,\text{s}$$
Converting this to customary units yields $3.96\times 10^6\,\text{lbf}\,\text{s}$.

Doing the exact same calculation, this time using customary units, yields
$$I_t = (217.5\,\text{s})(32.17405\,\text{ft}/\text{s}^2)(280\, \text{lbm}/\text{s})(65\,\text{s}) = 1.2736\times 10^8\,\text{but in what units?}$$
The dimensional analysis says the units of this expression are lbm·ft/s. Those aren't the desired units; you want lbf·s. The metric F=ma becomes F=kma in customary units. Dividing by the numerical value of *g*<sub>0</sub> converts lbm·ft/s<sup>2</sup> to lbf. That same division here converts lbm·ft/s to lbf·s. And indeed, 1.2736×10<sup>8</sup>/32.17405 is 3.96×10<sup>6</sup>.

This suggests an alternate expression, $I_t = I_{sp} \dot m \Delta t$, where $I_{sp}$ is in seconds.This yields a numerical value of 217.5·280·65=3.96×10<sup>6</sup>. That's the right value (at least numerically).  Note well: This alternate expression does not work in metric units. In metric, this calculation yields a value of 1.80×10<sup>6</sup> kg·s. The correct value is 1.76×10<sup>7</sup> N·s.

Strictly speaking, the above does not have the correct units; it has units of mass*time. Numerically, it yields the right value in customary units because dividing by the numerical value of *g*<sub>0</sub> cancels the explicit use of *g*<sub>0</sub> in the numerator.

This calculation is not correct in metric units. To get the right metric units from this calculation one needs to multiply the numerical value of that result (1.80×10<sup>6</sup> kg·s) by the numerical value of *g*<sub>0</sub>. Indeed, 1.80×10<sup>6</sup> * 9.80665 = 1.76×10<sup>7</sup>.

Comment: Argh! I hate English units! Thanks so much :)

Comment: Yeah, I gather it's widely used in the US still, but we barely touch English units here in South Africa. after a year of physics, I should have at least been able to check this via dimensional analysis. Fail. Hahaha. Well, I am on holiday after all. :)

Comment: Yes, they're still widely used here, particularly in engineering. (Note: real "rocket science" isn't a science. It's engineering.) US-based physicists are purely metric. In chemistry, it's a mix. In engineering, that's where you see a lot of English units. It costs money to make the switch from customary to English units, sometimes lots and lots and lots of money.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in as an Englishman - we don't use imperial units anymore. We went formally went metric back in 1965! :p

Comment: @FraserOfSmeg: You started going metric in 1965, and you aren't all the way there yet. For example, this photo, taken in 2013: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cc/Tomatoes_for_sale_in_a_UK_greengrocer%27s_shop_2013.jpg/269px-Tomatoes_for_sale_in_a_UK_greengrocer%27s_shop_2013.jpg . That's not going metric. It's kinda-sorta pretending to do so.

Comment: Wasn't this a problem with a Mars orbiter way back when?

Comment: @DuncanDean - Yes. Mars Climate Orbiter, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter .

Comment: An interesting side note: There are various branches of engineering where calculations are easier if one uses pounds-force and pounds-mass instead of using consistent units such as metric (or pounds-force, slugs, feet, and seconds in the US). US engineers who deal with these problems tout customary units as a virtue because of this. What's interesting to me is that the European counterparts of these engineers oftentimes use the banned kilopond instead of the newton as a unit of force.

Comment: Wow, that is interesting! However, I'm probably not going to stray too far at all from SI units doing a degree in physics. I don't know why I didn't convert everything in the question anyway.

Comment: That's my preferred technique. Convert all those nasty non-SI values to SI, do everything in metric where F=ma etc., and convert back if needed as output.

Comment: @DavidHammen I wasn't born in 1965, I was (I like to think) born metric! :)

Answer (score -2):

You take the effective exhaust velocity and multiply it by the mass flow. That gives you the thrust. Multiply that by the operating time and you get the total impulse.

Comment: This works great in metric. It doesn't with customary units: numerically, 7000*280*65=1.2736×10$^8$, but in what units? It's in the wrong units. Stupid English system strikes again!

Comment: The reason this doesn't work in English units is because exhaust velocity (in feet/second) times flow rate (in pounds/second) doesn't give thrust (in pounds force). You need to divide by the numerical value of $g_0$. Thrust in pounds is (7000 ft/s)*(280 lbm/s)*(1/32.17405 (lbf/(lbm·m/s^2))), or 60919 lbf. Multiplying this by 65 seconds yields the correct answer of 3.96 million lbf·s.

Comment: @DavidHammen Hammen: Well, sure you have to do your unit math. I don't think the answer deserves downvotes, though.